# ¿Cómo se referencia un archivo php en Ajax que está en otro directorio?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un archivo que a través de Jquery, invoca un php de ejecuta una consulta a base de datos. La invocación se realiza a través de Ajax de la siguiente forma:

```
    $.ajax(
    { 
        url:"buscar_bodega.php",
        data: bod,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function(respuesta)
            {
```

He querido organizar la estructura de los directorios del sistema y creé un directorio "querys" para almacenar todos los archivos php que se invocan por el aplicativo y que ejecutan consultas a la base de datos. Este directorio está dentro del mismo directorio padre donde están los archivos php de consulta, quedando de la siguiente forma el Ajax:

```
    $.ajax(
    { 
        url:"/querys/buscar_bodega.php",
        data: bod,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function(respuesta)
            {
```

pero ahora la invocación no funciona. Entiendo que el problema está en la forma de invocar la url.

Comment: lo haz probado así: `../querys/buscar_bodega.php` ?

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó muy bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por como estás colocando la url del archivo.
Ponla relativa, es decir:

```
$.ajax(
    { 
        url:"../querys/buscar_bodega.php",
        data: bod,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function(respuesta)
        {
```

Avisanos si esto funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfectamente.